# Using an IValueConverter to enable/disable button's IsDefault Property

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, ivalueconverter

My view has 2 buttons called BrowseButton and UploadButton.

BrowseButton [is default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) and UploadButton is not. My goal is for the default to change after BrowseButton is clicked (ie BrowseButton is not default but UploadButton is).

When BrowseButton is clicked, a Property (string) in my ViewModel is set. This means I can bind to that property and pass the value of that property to my IValueConverter and return either a true or false. This works as desired.

My BoolConverter looks like

```
 public class BoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Convert.ToString(value)))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And my Xaml

```
<Button Content="Browse for file" Width="150" Margin="5" Command="{Binding BrowseForFileCommand}" IsDefault="{Binding File, Converter={StaticResource BConverter}}" />
<Button Content="Upload" Width="75" Margin="5" Command="{Binding UploadCommand}"  IsDefault="{Binding File, Converter={StaticResource BConverter}}" />
```

The problem is, they both bind to the same BoolConverter class and as such are both equal (ie if one is false then both are false!). Again, I can understand why.

My question is, how do I get around this? Is it really just a case of having multiple Converter classes?

EG

```
public class BoolConverterForThis : IValueConverter
{//implementation}
public class BoolConverterForThat : IValueConverter
{//implementation}
public class BoolConverterForOther : IValueConverter
{//implementation}
```

Comment: why not define two bool properties in your viewmodel like `CanUpload`,`CanBrowse` and bind to the directly??

Comment: I did think of this, but it felt wrong to use the ViewModel for a UI function; I felt the ViewModel should hold data only. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to do something like this:

```
public class StringIsEmptyToBoolConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public StringIsEmptyToBoolConverter()
    {
        this.Result = false;
    }

    public bool Result { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? this.Result : !this.Result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

which you could use in you Xaml like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication2:StringIsEmptyToBoolConverter 
        x:Key="TrueResultConverter" Result="True"/>
    <wpfApplication2:StringIsEmptyToBoolConverter 
        x:Key="FalseResultConverter" Result="False"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!-- because the converter derives from MarkupExtension you can 
         create an instance directly instead of creating a resource -->
    <Button IsDefault="{Binding File,
          Converter={wpfApplication2:StringIsEmptyToBoolConverter Result=True}}"/>

    <!-- or use a resource -->
    <Button IsDefault="{Binding File, 
          Converter={StaticResource TrueResultConverter}}"/>
    <Button IsDefault="{Binding File, 
          Converter={StaticResource FalseResultConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. I like this because of it's re-use, I've learned something and, it works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Further reading on MarkupExtension if helpful to anyone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747254.aspx

Comment: based upon your answer, can I assume it is typical to have multiple Converter classes (instead of trying to create 1 'God-like' class to handle everything)?

Comment: Yes, usually lots of converters.

Comment: Phil, thank you for taking the time, this has helped make a few things that little bit clearer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to resort to coding a True Visibility converter and False Visiility converter.
Not that you can't code a visibility converter, but for the benefit of someone who doesn't, this is what my code looked like.

```
public class TrueVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visibility = (bool)value;
        return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
        return (visibility == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}



public class FalseVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool visibility = (bool)value;
            return visibility ? Visibility.Collapsed:Visibility.Visible ;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            return (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed);
        }
    }
```